# Uncaught TypeError: contentEditable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am trying to create a button with a function that will enable or disable `contenteditable` for all `<div>`'s however I get that `contentEditable` is not a function, anyone know why?

```js
function contentEditable() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("editable");
    if ($(this).attr("contentEditable") == "true") {
        console.log=(hello);
        x.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
        button.innerHTML = "Enable content of p to be editable!";
    } else {
        x.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'false');
        button.innerHTML = "Disable content of p to be editable!";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="contentEditable(this);" id="contentEdit" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Edit Text</button>
```

Comment: Your script probably isn't running or is failing before `contentEditable()` gets defined. We need a http://jsfiddle.net/ example to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Indeed the order of code will matter here. Also getElementsByCLassName returns a live nodelist, so you need to access the first node, x[0]. Also `console.log=(helllo);` is a typo.

Comment: It could be that the initial value for the property ```contentEditable``` is not ```"true"``` but ```"inherit"```?

Comment: Also the logic is flawed. `this` will be the button, while it's the <p> that ahs the contenteditable, so you have to check 'x' instead of $(this) for the attr.

Comment: also, `button.innerHTML` for buttons are reversed in logic. should be contentEditable == false ? "*Enable* ...." : "*Disable*...." (using shorthand explanation.. hehe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many issues I'll just post an annotated example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- make sure contenteditable is set to false initially -->
<div class="editable" contenteditable="false">some text 1</div>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="false">some text 2</div>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="false">some text 3</div>
<button id="contentEdit" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Edit Text</button>
<script>
var button = document.querySelector('#contentEdit');
var contentEditable = function contentEditable() {
    // getElementsByClassName returns a nodelist,so we ahve to cast it to an array, or use a basic for-loop.
    var editables = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("editable"));
    editables.forEach(function( x ) {
        // We want to check the <div> tag for editable, not the button
        // the correct attribute is lowercase contenteditable
        if (x.getAttribute("contenteditable") === 'false') {
            // fixed syntax
            console.log("hello");
            x.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
            // swicthed around Disable and Enable in the strings to make the logic correct.
            button.innerHTML = "Disable content of p to be editable!";
        } else {
            x.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
            button.innerHTML = "Enable content of p to be editable!";
        }   
    });
};
button.addEventListener("click", contentEditable);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working but it is changing contenteditable from "false to "true" only for one div while I want it to change it for all divs inside #content-link2

Comment: Then you have to loop over all the  divs. Sorry, missed that part since you didn't show any loop either.

Comment: It is because I didn't have any loop, can you update a answer to show me how it is done? an example of course.

Comment: Done. Good luck implementing it in your own app. Most steps can be replaced by their jquery equivalent.

Comment: Brilliant, works absolutely perferct and thank you for fixing mistakes

Comment: I hope you take the time to see what was wrong with your own code as well. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `contentEditable` function loaded inside the page and its not defined inside any other function. Try to execute `contentEditable` function from chrome or firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from other errors you have in your code, main issue was your function is not accessible. here's a fiddle where I've put `contentEditable()` in document, so using it in button `<button onclick="document.contentEditable()">`

```js
document.contentEditable = function() {
  var divs = $("div.editable"),
    button = $("#btn"),
    attr;
  divs.each(function(index, item) {
    attr = $(this).attr('contentEditable');
    $(this).attr('contentEditable', attr == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
    
  });
  button.html(attr == 'true' ? 'Disable' : 'Enable');
  //console.log(divs);
}
```

```css
div.editable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

[contentEditable="true"] {
  background: black;
}

[contentEditable="false"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable="true" class="editable"></div>
<div contentEditable="true" class="editable"></div>
<div contentEditable="true" class="editable"></div>
<div contentEditable="true" class="editable"></div>
<div contentEditable="true" class="editable"></div>

<button id="btn" onclick="document.contentEditable();">Disable</button>
```

But since you already are using **Jquery**, why not use something like:

```
$(":button")//you can use any selector for your button, id perhaps?
.on('click', function() { //your code... });
```

Answer (score -2):

you have missed to pass the parameter into you function definition:

```
function contentEditable(obj) {
    // replace all this with obj
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("editable");
    if ($(obj).attr("contentEditable") == "true") {
        console.log=(hello);
        x.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
        button.innerHTML = "Enable content of p to be editable!";
    } else {
        x.setAttribute('contentEditable', 'false');
        button.innerHTML = "Disable content of p to be editable!";
    }
}
```

Comment: are you guessing?

Comment: no i have tried and then error changed to `x.setAttribute` is not defined, it means its went into the function and error is because of i have not defined `x.setAttribute`

Comment: because x is a node list.. should be `x[0]` to access first `div`. so basically, there is no `setAttribute` for a `node list`.

Comment: yes you are right because  dom selects array of all element objects